# ANTLR - Token Enumeration Mismatch Between Grammar and Tree Grammar

Tags: java, antlr, dsl, antlr3, antlrworks

### BackGround

I am trying to write a simple grammar, using AntlrWorks, for boolean equations that test sets of values for the existence (or lack there of) of specified elements.
I have created a combined lexer/parser grammar that produces the desired ASTs.
I have also written a cooresponding tree grammar, that seems to work (passes AntlrWorks' debug functions).

---

### Problem

However, When I try to wire the two together in a test program (that is lex, parse, and tree parse in the same program), I get errors like...

`node from line 1:5 required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input 'and'`

and

`node from after line 1:8 mismatched tree node: UP expecting <DOWN>`

As a sanity test, I had the test program output the results of `toStringTree()` from the generated AST and `toTokenTypeString()` from the resulting `TreeNodeStream`.

What I found was that the enumerated token type values of the `TreeNodeStream` do not match the enumerated token type values in the autogenerated Tree Grammar code.

---

### EXAMPLE

- sample input: `"true and false"`
- Output of toStringTree() from the Parser supplied tree: `(and true false)`
- Output of `toTokenTypeString()` from TreeNodeStream conatining the above AST: `19 2 22 20 3 8`

That token stream should be `AND <DOWN> 'true' 'false' <UP> NEWLINE`
But the TreeParser sees it as `CLOSEPAREN <DOWN> OR 'false' <UP> OPENPAREN` (based off of looking at the node token type output and checking it against the enumeration defined in the tree grammar) and throws the error

`1:5 required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input 'and'`

---

### Bottom Line

**Why isn't my tree parser set up to properly identify my ASTs?**

Below is my source.  I appreciate any feedback on the foolish mistakes I must have made :)

Lexer/Parser Grammar

```
grammar INTc;

options {
   output=AST;
   ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

tokens {
   OR='or';
   AND='and';
   NOT='not';
   ALLIN='+';
   PARTIN='^';
   NOTIN='!';
   SET;
   OPENPAREN='(';
   CLOSEPAREN=')';
   OPENSET='{';
   CLOSESET='}';
}
@header {
package INTc;
}

@lexer::header {
package INTc;
}

@members {
}

/**Begin Parser Rules*/
prog:   stat+ ;

stat:   expr
    |   NEWLINE
    ;

expr
:  orExpr
;

orExpr returns [boolean value]
    :   a=andExpr(OR^ b=andExpr)*
    ;

andExpr returns [boolean value]
    :   a=notExpr (AND^ b=notExpr)*
    ; 

notExpr returns [boolean value]
    :   a=atom
    | '!' a=atom -> ^(NOT atom)
    ;

atom returns [boolean value]
    :   ALLIN  OPENSET ((INT)(','INT)*) CLOSESET   -> ^(ALLIN ^(SET INT+))
    |   PARTIN  OPENSET ((INT)(','INT)*) CLOSESET  -> ^(PARTIN ^(SET INT+))
    |   NOTIN OPENSET ((INT)(','INT)*) CLOSESET   -> ^(NOTIN  ^(SET INT+))
    |   TIMERANGE
    |   OPENPAREN! e=expr CLOSEPAREN!
    |   'true'
    |   'false'
    ;

/**Begin Lexer Rules*/
ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')* ;
DIGIT   :   ('0'..'9');
INT :   DIGIT+ ;
NEWLINE :   '\r'? '\n' ;
WS  :   ( ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;};
COMMENT
    :   '//' ~('\n'|'\r')* '\r'? '\n' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    |   '/*' ( options {greedy=false;} : . )* '*/' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
```

Tree Grammar

```
tree grammar INTcWalker;

options {
  tokenVocab=INTc;
  ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

@header {
  package INTc;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Arrays;
}

@members {
  ArrayList<String> intSet;
  boolean isFit = false;

  public boolean getResult() {
     return isFit;   
  }
  public void setINTSet(ArrayList newSet) {
     intSet = newSet;
     isFit = false;
  }
  public ArrayList getINTSET(){return intSet;}
}

prog
:     stat+
;
stat
:     expr  {
                                     isFit = $expr.value;
                                     //System.out.println(isFit);
    }
|    NEWLINE {}
;
expr returns [boolean value]
: ^(OR a=expr b=expr){}
| ^(AND a=expr b=expr){}
| ^(NOT a=expr){}
| ^(ALLIN ^(SET INT+)){}
| ^(PARTIN ^(SET INT+)){}
| ^(NOTIN ^(SET INT+)){}
| 'true'        {$value = true;}
| 'false'       {$value = false;}
;
```

Test Program

```
public class setTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        INTcLexer lex = new INTcLexer(new ANTLRFileStream("input.txt"));
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);

        INTcParser parser = new INTcParser(tokens);
        INTcParser.prog_return r = parser.prog();
        CommonTree t  = (CommonTree)r.getTree();
        CommonTreeNodeStream nodes = new CommonTreeNodeStream(t);
        INTcWalker evaluator = new INTcWalker(nodes);

        System.out.println(t.toStringTree());

        System.out.println(nodes.toTokenTypeString());
        nodes.reset();

        try {
                evaluator.prog();
        } catch (RecognitionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }   

        System.out.println(evaluator.getResult());

    }   
}
```

Comment: My goodness, such a well written first question is a rare occaission! I cannot help, but welcome to S.O.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I use your combined grammar and tree grammar to create lexer, parser and tree-walker classes, and run the following class:

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    INTcLexer lex = new INTcLexer(new ANTLRStringStream("true and false\n"));
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
    INTcParser parser = new INTcParser(tokens);

    CommonTree t  = (CommonTree)parser.prog().getTree();
    CommonTreeNodeStream nodes = new CommonTreeNodeStream(t);
    INTcWalker evaluator = new INTcWalker(nodes);

    System.out.println(t.toStringTree());

    CommonTree tr;
    while(true) {
      Token token = ((CommonTree)nodes.nextElement()).getToken();
      if(token.getType() == INTcParser.EOF) break;
      System.out.printf("%-10s '%s'\n", INTcParser.tokenNames[token.getType()], token.getText());
    }

    System.out.println("\nresult=" + evaluator.getResult());
  }
}
```

the following is printed to the console:

```
(and true false) 

AND        'and'
<DOWN>     'DOWN'
'true'     'true'
'false'    'false'
<UP>       'UP'
NEWLINE    '
'

result=false
```

I.e.: I see the expected output:

- the tree is okay (`(and true false)`);
- `CommonTreeNodeStream` contains the proper tokens (or better: trees);
- and the correct value, `false`, is being printed without any errors from either the parser or tree walker.

---

A couple of tips:

- create tokens for both `'true'` and `'false'` (i.e. `TRUE='true';` ...);
- don't use literals inside your tree grammar (not `'true'`, but `TRUE`);
- make `DIGIT` a `fragment` rule, that way it will never become a token of its own, but only used inside `INT` (or other lexer rules). Simply place the keyword `fragment` in front of it;
- both `.*` and `.+` are ungreedy by default, so you can remove the `options greedy=false;} :`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response.  I solved the issue with the tokens.  It turns out, my tree grammar was pulling it's token list from an older (mismatched) token file.  However, I still get `node from line 0:0 required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input 'EOF'` when I give it a simple input like `true or false` (this is when I run `evaluator.prog()` from setTest).  I am having a lot of trouble figuring out why this is happening.

Comment: Everything works now, Thanks.
<br/>
Things I learned:
<br/>
 - Having duplicate token files ANYWHERE in the project hierarchy (even if you think they are "set aside") will throw a monkey wrench into compilation.
<br/>
 - fragments are very useful